# How do I end the first instance of the timer so that the two timers wont over lap

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I have this issue when I press the rest button to rest for 5 mins but the 25 mins from the start function keeps ongoing, as a result, the 2 timers overlap with each other and requiring to reset for it to work properly again.

```py
from tkinter import *
import math

PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"
WORK_MIN = 25
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20
reps = 0
timer = None


def reset_timer():
    window.after_cancel(timer)
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text="00:00")
    title_label.config(text="Timer")
    check_marks.config(text="")
    global reps
    reps = 0

def start_timer():
    work_sec = WORK_MIN * 60
    count_down(work_sec)
    title_label.config(text="Work", fg=GREEN)

def rest_time():
    global reps
    reps = 1
    reps += 1
    short_break_sec = SHORT_BREAK_MIN * 60
    long_break_sec = LONG_BREAK_MIN * 60
    if reps % 8 == 0:
        count_down(long_break_sec)
        title_label.config(text="Break", fg=RED)
    # If it's the 8th rep
    elif reps % 2 == 0:
        count_down(short_break_sec)
        title_label.config(text="Break", fg=PINK)
    # If it's the 2nd/4th/6th rep


def count_down(count):
    count_min = math.floor(count / 60)
    count_sec = count % 60
    if count_sec < 10:
        count_sec = f"0{count_sec}"
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{count_min}:{count_sec}")
    if count > 0:
        global timer
        timer = window.after(1000, count_down, count - 1)
    else:
        start_timer()
        marks = ""
        work_sessions = math.floor(reps/2)
        for _ in range(work_sessions):
            marks += "✓"
        check_marks.config(text=marks)


window.config(padx=100, pady=50, bg=YELLOW)
title_label = Label(text="Timer", fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 50))
title_label.grid(column=1, row=0)
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
timer_text = canvas.create_text(100, 130, text="00:00", fill="white", font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)
start_button = Button(text="Start", highlightthickness=0, command=start_timer)
start_button.grid(column=0, row=2)
rest_button = Button(text="Rest", highlightthickness=0, command=rest_time)
rest_button.grid(column=1, row=2)
reset_button = Button(text="Reset", highlightthickness=0, command=reset_timer)
reset_button.grid(column=2, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should you cancel the current count down inside `rest_time()`?

Answer (score 0):

> from the start function keeps ongoing, as a result, the 2 timers
> overlap with each other

What you are looking for is how to change the button state.

Comment out line 22 and 67 `check_marks.config(text="")`

code:

```
def reset_timer():
    window.after_cancel(timer)
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text="00:00")
    title_label.config(text="Timer")
    rest_button['state']= NORMAL
    start_button['state']= NORMAL
    
    global reps
    reps = 0

def rest_time():
...

start_button['state']= DISABLED
```